# Java - how best to perform set-like operations (e.g. retainAll) based on custom comparison

Tags: java, set

I have two sets both containing the same object types. I would like to be able to access the following:

- the intersection of the 2 sets
- the objects contained in set 1 and not in set 2
- the objects contained in set 2 and not in set 1

My question relates to how best to compare the two sets to acquire the desired views. The class in question has numerous id properties which can be used to uniquely identify that entity. However, there are also numerous properties in the class that describe the current status of the object. The two sets can contain objects that match according to the ids, but which are in a different state (and as such, not all properties are equal between the two objects).

So - how do I best implement my solution. To implement an equals() method for the class which does not take into account the status properties and only looks at the id properties would not seem to be very true to the name 'equals' and could prove to be confusing later on. Is there some way I can provide a method through which the comparisons are done for the set methods?

Also, I would like to be able to access the 3 views described above without modifying the original sets.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: implement `equals` based on the entity's key, not state.

Slightly longer version: What the `equals` method should check depends on the type of object. For something that's considered a "value" object (say, an `Integer` or `String` or an `Address`), equality is typically based on all fields being the same. For an object with a set of fields that uniquely identify it (its primary key), equality is typically based on the fields of the primary key only. Equality doesn't necessarily need to (and often shouldn't) take in to consideration the state of an object. It needs to determine whether two objects are representations of the same thing. Also, for objects that are used in a `Set` or as keys in a `Map`, the fields that are used to determine equality should generally not be mutable, since changing them could cause a `Set`/`Map` to stop working as expected.

Once you've implemented `equals` like this, you can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to view the differences between the two sets:

```
Set<Foo> notInSet2 = Sets.difference(set1, set2);
Set<Foo> notInSet1 = Sets.difference(set2, set1);
```

Both difference sets will be live views of the original sets, so changes to the original sets will automatically be reflected in them.

Answer (score 4):

(Edit: My first suggestion has been removed because of an unfortunate implementation detail in `TreeSet`, as pointed out by Martin Konecny. <strike>Some collection classes (e.g. `TreeSet`) allow you to supply a `Comparator` that is to be used to compare elements, so you might want to use one of those classes - at least, if there is some natural way of ordering your objects.</strike>)

If not (i.e. if it would be difficult to implement `CompareTo()`, while it would be simpler to implement `HashCode()` and `Equals()`), you could create a wrapper class which implements those two functions by looking at the relevant fields from the objects they wrap, and create a regular `HashSet` of these wrapper objects.

Comment: I do not require my sets to be ordered, so using a TreeSet would add some unnecessary overhead. Is there no in-between option?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (among Java's standard collections). But maybe someone else knows of an alternative. You could implement your own hashmap, but that would be quite error-prone.

Comment: (By the way, you should try `TreeSet` and measure its performance before making conclusions about whether it would bee "too much overhead".)

Comment: You could extend `HashSet` and adding for instance a `Comparator` to the constructor and overriding the `equals()` method to use the comparator. However, this will likely be inconsistent with equals, meaning the `HashSet` will fail to find elements again. Wrapping the elements or using a `SortedSet` are then your only choices. Asamund is right, the standard implementations of `SortedSet` are fast.

Comment: I'm not even sure this approach would work. See this "Won't Fix" from 2002: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4730113

Comment: @MartinKonecny: Interesting - I removed my `TreeSet` suggestion. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

This is a requirement for which the Standard C++ Library fares better with its [`set` type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), which accepts a comparator for this purpose. In the Java library, your need is modeled better by a `Map`— one mapping from your [*candidate key*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) to either the rest of the status-related fields, or to the complete object that happens to also contain the candidate key. (Note that the C++ `set` type is mandated to be some sort of balanced tree, usually implemented as a *red-black tree*, which means it's equivalent to [Java's `TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), which does accept a custom `Comparator`.) It's ugly to duplicate the data, but it's also ugly to try to work around it, as you've already found.

If you have control over the type in question and can split it up into separate candidate key and status parts, you can eliminate the duplication. If you can't go that far, consider combining the candidate key fields into a single object held within your larger, complete object; that way, the `Map` key type will be the same as that candidate key type, and the only storage overhead will be the map keys' object references. The candidate key data would not be duplicated.

Note that most set types are implemented as maps under the covers; they map from the would-be set element type to something like a Boolean flag. Apparently there's too much code that would be duplicated in wholly disjoint set and map types. Once you realize that, backing up from using a set in an awkward way to using a map no longer seems to impose the storage overhead you thought it would.

It's a somewhat depressing realization, having chosen the mathematically correct idealized data structure, only to find it's a false choice down a layer or two, but even in your case your problem sounds better suited to a map representation than a set. Think of it as an *index*.

Comment: So, using a map, how do you suggest I acquire the 3 views of the data I need described above? I don't believe Map has the retainAll style methods. I should implement my own, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: You could use `Map#keySet()` to get the indices as sets, copy one of them, and then use `Set#retainAll()` against the copy to form the intersection. Unfortunately, you'd the have to go back into the map and retrieve the values corresponding to those keys if you need the "whole objects" in hand. For your set difference operations, again you could get hold of both key sets from the maps, make a copy of one side, and use `Set#removeAll()` against the copy to subtract out the other set, leaving the difference. Needing to make the copies first is unfortunate when the differences will be small.